# How do I hook into tkinters FileDialog?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Using `python 3` and `tkinter` I'm trying to create a file dialog that lets the user select existing directories (`exists=True`).

When they select `choose` I'd like to check that the directory is also readable and I can get a file lock. Since the rest of my program will rely read access to the path and it's processes will take a long time.

Whey they select `cancel` I'd like the dialog to close.

[image: File Dialogue]

If the directory is not `readable` I'd like the file dialogue to display a `askretry` message. Clicking `Retry` will take them back to choose a file. clicking `Cancel` will close the dialogue.

[image: Ask Retry Dialogue]

In my first attempt, a novice to `tkinter`, I created this:

```
import os
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox


class OpenDialog(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.directory_path = None
        self.dialog_title ="Photos Directory Selection"

    def ask_for_directory(self):
        while not self.directory_path:
            self.directory_path = filedialog.askdirectory(mustexist=True, title=self.dialog_title)
            if not os.access(os.path.dirname(self.directory_path), os.F_OK):
                self.directory_path = None
                if not messagebox.askretrycancel(title=self.dialog_title, message="Can't read directory."):
                   break
```

Although its not perfect. It won't let you `cancel` the file dialogue.

But alas, I thought I could potentially hook into the file dialogue itself...

I just can't see how I could cleanly hook into the FileDialogue class to cleanly display a `askretry` dialogue and repeat the process.

[filedialogue.py](http://pastebin.com/z1YNiVsx)

If there is something I'm missing please share :-)

Comment: Why not wait for the return from the dialog, check the path (if the user didn't cancel), then just call the dialog again if required?

Comment: I think the problem is `filedialog.askdirectory` returns the file path and not a `bool`. If I could get the `bool` and `file_path` separately that would work.

Comment: What boolean are you expecting?

Comment: The `cancel` boolean?

Comment: It's not a boolean, you get a blank path if the user cancels (although as an empty string is false-y, you can still test e.g.  `if path:`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works, but does anyone see an issue with recursive call?

```
def ask_for_directory(self):
    self.directory_path = filedialog.askdirectory(mustexist=True, title=self.dialog_title)
    if self.directory_path:

        # Check that we have access to the path
        if not os.access(self.directory_path, os.R_OK):

            # If we don't have access
            if messagebox.askretrycancel(title=self.dialog_title, message="Can't read directory."):
                self.ask_for_directory()
```

EDIT:

Here is my example but corrected to work...

```
def ask_for_directory(self):
    while not self.directory_path:
        self.directory_path = filedialog.askdirectory(mustexist=True, title=self.dialog_title)
        if self.directory_path:
            if not os.access(self.directory_path, os.R_OK):
                self.directory_path = None
                if not messagebox.askretrycancel(title=self.dialog_title, message="Can't read directory."):
                   break
        else:
            break
```